# Eclipse RCP menu command is displayed as active although the command is not enabled

Tags: eclipse, menu, command, rcp

I have a strange problem with menu commands.

I want to make a menu command that is active on some conditions but inactive on others (ex: close command is active when a particular entity is opened but inactive when there is no such entity)

I have tried two strategies:

- overriding the `isEnabled()` method of a Handler to contain the logic that should tell it whether the command is active or not
- extending an `AbstractSourceProvider` that listens to the state and changes the provided variabile.

In both approaches the code works ok, the menu contribution getting activated and deactivead. However, and this is the problem, it does this only if I switch to another application(alt tab to something else) and switch back. If don't do this switching only the command gets inactive but the menu contribution still shows it as active, resulting in a `NotEnabledException`.

The `SourceProviderApproach` extension point looks something like this:

```
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?before=window">
     <menu
           label="File">
        <command
              commandId="profile.close"
              label="Close"
              style="push">
           <activeWhen
              checkEnabled="false">
           <with
                 variable="profile.gui.ActiveProfile">
              <equals
                    value="active">
              </equals>
           </with>
        </activeWhen>
        </command>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

If I change it to `validWhen` everything is ok, the command is shown and hid accordingly. But If I switch it to `activeWhen` then the situation above appears, I have to switch to another application and come back in order for that menu contribution to appear active or inactive.

I also spent 4 hours debugging Eclipse code trying to pinpoint the problem but I wasn't able to find anything.

Did someone else run into this and found a workaround?

Thanks,
Mihai

Answer (score 0):

**org.eclipse.ui.menus** command elements only support visibleWhen, not activeWhen (since the **command** will be enabled or handled, the menu item simply refers to a command).

**org.eclipse.ui.handlers** supports activeWhen (which determines *if* a handler can be active at a given point) and enabledWhen (which will answer that handlers enabled state based on the enabledWhen expression).

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I found a workaround. 
As far as I can tell, this is an Eclipse Bug. In some cases it triggers the label update in function of the underlying associated command state(if the command is disabled so should the label) like when minimizing the window but in some cases it does not, like when you just invoke the menu after the command has been disabled.

So the temporary solution is to manually trigger the filling of the menus. This can be done with the following code snippet:

```
    public static void refillAllActionBars() {
        IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
        WorkbenchWindow ww = (WorkbenchWindow)workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

        ww.fillActionBars(ActionBarAdvisor.FILL_STATUS_LINE);
}
```

A lot of snooping around for just three lines of code :(

Comment: This accesses internal code and AFAIK won't even work in Eclipse 4.x, where `WorkbenchWindow` has been replaced.